# In flex, how to make a component appear on the center of screen?

Tags: apache-flex, components, center

In Flex, how to put some component ( like canvas ) appear at the center of the screen. ( even if there is scroll, it should be displayed at the center of the current view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PopUpManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#centerPopUp%28%29)'s centerPopUp will do this easy, if that is what you're after.

But, if you want to display something in the center of a container that is a bit different.  In that sitaution, you'll probably either have to write your own positioning code (in updateDisplayList() ) to center the component and position the others.